# Making list of unique numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a list of unique numbers and I am getting the wrong output.

I want to get each unique number from a file where each line has two numbers: 
friends=['4 6', '4 7', '4 8', '5 9', '6 8', '7 8', '100 112', '112 114', '78 44']

Answer: 
user=['4', '6', '7', '8','44','78', '100', '112', '114']

However my following code outputs user= ['0', '1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'] instead

I am unsure of how to make my code recognize two and three digit numbers in the file, basically this my problem

```
user=[]
for row in friends:
    for column in row:
            if column not in user and column.isdigit():
                user.append(column)

    user.sort()
print(user)
```

*I am not allowed to use dictionaries, sets, deque, bisect module

Comment: numbers in quotes (like `'4 6'`) are strings and python handles them as strings, not numbers (like `int`), when you read the file contents, you need to convert the values to `int` before doing comparisons.

Comment: @downshift I tried to do this but I was getting an error because of the space between the numbers, please how would convert the values and maintain the structure?

Comment: @h-g try these two steps: `temp = map(lambda x: x.split(), friends)`, then `numbers = [[int(letter) for letter in x] for x in temp]`. Then you'll have `print(numbers)` output `[[4, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8], [5, 9], [6, 8], [7, 8], [100, 112], [112, 114], [78, 44]]`. These are now lists of lists of `int`s, but you can structure the numbers however you like.

Comment: @downshift Thank you it works! Can you please breakdown these into a function that I can call with friends as parameter.. I am not familiar with using lambda

Comment: @h-g, ok I'll post a function in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
friends=['4 6', '4 7', '4 8', '5 9', '6 8', '7 8', '100 112', '112 114', '78 44']

def get_numbers(mylist):
    nums = []                            # create a new list
    for i in mylist:                     # for each pair in the friends list
        nums.append(map(int, i.split())) # split each pair
                                         # convert them to integers
                                         # and append them to the new list
    return nums                          # return the new list

numbers = get_numbers(friends)           # call the function with the old list
```

then you can do:

```
print(numbers)   
[[4, 6], [4, 7], [4, 8], [5, 9], [6, 8], [7, 8], [100, 112], [112, 114], [78, 44]]
```

This should help get you started. If you get stuck, post a comment, and we can update it.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with map as well, does this mean I need to create two functions 1) That splits each pair 2) makes the numbers integers

Answer (score 1):

@downshift, I think I got it!! Thank you :)

```
def get_numbers(mylist):
    nums = [] 
    for i in mylist:                     
        nums.append(i.split())
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(len(nums[0])):
                nums[i][j]= int(nums[i][j])
    return nums 

print(get_numbers(mylist))
```

Comment: great job! yes you got it :)